# Regarding String array declaration

Tags: java, string

I have the below String assignment statement

```
String items[] = line.split("\",\"",15);
String fileNamet = items[1].replaceAll("\"","").trim();
```

I need to introduce a new if statement

```
if (valid) {
    String items[] = line.split("\",\"",15);
} else {
    String items[] = line.split("\",\"",16);
} 
String fileNamet = items[1].replaceAll("\"","").trim();
```

Now items becomes local to the if loop and is giving me compilation errors. How can I declare the items array outside the if loop?

Comment: Please format code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help If you were a newbie, I'd do it for you, but this is your 24th question -- you should be on this by now. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the kinds of scenarios where the ternary operator excels at ([JLS 15.25 Conditional Operator ?:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25))

```
String[] items = line.split("\",\"", (valid ? 15 : 16));
```

No code is repeated, and once you get used to it, it reads much better.

That said, you can also pull out the declaration outside of the `if` if that's what you're more comfortable with.

```
String[] items;
if (valid) {
  items = line.split("\",\"",15);
} else {
  items = line.split("\",\"",16);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. poly need some help with the below issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421760/regarding-java-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 1):

Declare it outside:

```
String items[];

if (valid) { 
    items = line.split("\",\"",15); 
} else { 
    items = line.split("\",\"",16); 
} 
String fileNamet = items[1].replaceAll("\"","").trim();
```