# Regarding Java Command Line Arguments

Tags: java, string

I have the below command line arguments set for the program. argument proc is mandatory  argument chgval is optional and  argument inputfile is optional.

./test.sh -proc mode1 -chval a  -inputfile b.csv

I need to modify the below function so that either one of the optional argument should exists in command line  arguments along with the mandatory argument proc .  If i have the two optional arguments chval , inputfile in  the command line along with the mandatory argument proc it's allowing now. I dont want it to happen it should throw an error.

Listed the valid values below and the rest should be an error

./test.sh -proc mode1 -chval a

./test.sh -proc mode1  -inputfile b.csv

./test.sh -proc mode1

```
 public static Options usage() {

      Option proc = OptionBuilder.withArgName("proc")
                                      .hasArg()
                                      .isRequired()
                                      .withDescription("Process Mode for testing:")

                                      .create("proc");
      Option chgval = OptionBuilder.withArgName("chgval")
                                      .hasArg()
                                      .withDescription("chg eeds to be Processed")
                                      .create("chgval");
      Option inputFile = OptionBuilder.withArgName("inputfile")
                                      .hasArg()
                                      .withDescription("Name of the input file")
                                      .create("inputfile");

      Options options = new Options();
      options.addOption(proc);
      options.addOption(chgval);
      options.addOption(inputFile);

      return options;
  }
```

What needs to be modified?

Comment: Smells like homework (as do all your other questions).  Please so tag them if they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dancrumb was correct, for mutually exclusive options you use [`OptionGroup`](http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-1.1/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionGroup.html). Here's how to use it for your case:

```
Options options = new Options();

OptionGroup group1 = new OptionGroup();
group1.addOption(chgval);
group1.addOption(inputFile);

options.addOption(proc);
options.addOptionGroup(group1);
```

So now, `chgval` and `inputFile` are mutually exclusive options. On an argument like `"-proc mode1 -chgval a -inputfile b.csv"`, it will throw an `AlreadySelectedException:` "The option `inputfile` was specified but an option from this group has already been selected: `chgval`".

By the way, I also noticed the inconsistency in your post between `chval` and `chgval`.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that `inputfile` and `chgval` should be mutually exclusive, then you should use [OptionGroup](http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-1.1/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionGroup.html)

Comment: What i need to change in the above function?